# Dilemma in way to implement MVC 4 add/edit/list Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working (actually refactoring) some project , I have an Admin panel , there are regular Admin actions ADD / EDIT / LIST that what they do , is inserting/ updating / or listing entities to/from database.

What I've found in this project , is that there is always duplication code between Add and Update ViewModels and Views , it's copy paste with minor changes between them. It's something like this:

EditCardsViewModel 
AddCardViewModel

almost absolutely identical , as I said , then EditCardVIew uses  EditCardsViewModel as Model , AddView uses AddCardViewModel ,as for me it's code duplication. When I've contacted the developer who created this , he said , that these are best practices , and it's very readable , you know where you can find everything ... and blah blah , I don't have enough experience to decide. So the question is what are best practices to this ? I mean can you please point me to some good article , explaining on how ADD/UPDATE/LIST should be done in MVC .

Thanks.

Comment: You 'could' inherit from a base view model for common properties, but it may make things more complex. Unless you have many views all sharing things, it may just be simpler to leave it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because Create and Edit are practically the same, I generally do something like this:

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public class ActivityController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = //Get your List model here...

            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new ActivityModel(); //Create new instance of whatever your model is
            return View("Edit", model); //NOTE: Pass the model to the "Edit view
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var model = // your logic here to get your model based on ID param
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                // your logic here to delete based on ID param
                return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "Entity updated" }); //AJAX result
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                return Json(new { Success = false, Message = x.GetBaseException().Message }); //AJAX result
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(ActivityModel model)//a single action to handle both add and edit operations
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Please correct any errors and try again" });//AJAX result
            }

            try
            {
                if (entity.Id == 0)
                {
                    //your logic for inserting
                }
                else
                {
                    //your logic for updating
                }

                return Json(new { Success = true });//AJAX result
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                return Json(new { Success = false, Message = x.GetBaseException().Message }); //AJAX result
            }
        }
    }
```

In this way, I mostly ever need to create 2 views: `Index.cshtml` and `Edit.cshtml`.

Just remember in your Edit view to have this:
`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)`

That will be used in the `Update()` action to check whether you need to do an insert or update.

Without seeing your code, I'm not sure if that applies to your situation though...

Comment: This is exactly what happens in my code , so you say , this is Best practices in MVC ? If so I will leave this as is ... Thanks

Comment: My example would be a little different to yours in that I am only using one model whereas you were using 2: 1 for edit and 1 for create. I just use the one model and then figure out what to do with it (insert or update) in the Update() action based on whether it has an ID > 0 or not. This way you don't have to maintain 2 separate classes and 2 separate views.

Comment: Wait , maybe I misunderstood something , you have 1 model for 2 separate views , right ?

Comment: both the Create() and Edit() actions are using the same Model and the same View.. since the UI will be exactly the same (in most of the cases I have seen anyway).. but like I said: I haven't seen your code, so I don't know if this is a suitable approach for you as well.

Comment: Maybe you didn't look carefully at the Create() action.. I am telling it to use the "Edit" view.

Answer (score 1):

If you download [MVCScaffolding](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding) the templates there are optimised for the AddEdit View type design.
This [Blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) is a helpful resource for using it.